# Name for IPv6 nameserver

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6, godaddy

I have a few name servers for my dns system. Let's say they are ns1.example.com, ns2.example.com. Previously they all resolved to IPv4 addresses. Now I'm planning to implement IPv6 for my dns system. So should I reuse ns1, ns2 for IPv6 name servers? Or should I change them to something different to avoid conflict? Thanks.

Comment: You might want to read up on a AAAA name record

Comment: I'm totally aware of AAAA records. If I use the same name, I have a problem setting glue records for both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. Godaddy doesn't allow duplicate hostnames for glue records.

Comment: @ElgsQianChen There's no technical reason why they shouldn't allow you to have `A` and `AAAA` glue records for the same name, that would actually be the normal thing to do. Are you positive that they don't allow this?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist, seems Godaddy doesn't allow. Here is a screenshot of their error message: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5310382/Screen_Shot_2015-10-08_at_12_36_06_PM.png

Comment: @ElgsQianChen I'm not familiar with that form but it looks like it might possible to add multiple IP addresses for the same hostname? (The numbered list for IP addresses at the bottom seems to suggest there could be multiple entries?)

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist they ask for a hostname for each IP addresses, and they don't allow duplicate hostname. Not sure whether the hostname for the glue records have to be the same as the AAAA records.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist I get it work now. It looks like I cannot edit another glue record to share the same name as an existing one. But I can add new IP addresses for the existing one. Thank you for reminding.

Comment: @ElgsQianChen please post that as an answer so you can accept it in a few days. That way this question won't sit around in the un-answered queue for years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `A` and `AAAA` record types can coexist at the same owner name.

Normally you would just add both types of address records for the same hostname for a dual-stack host, this also applies to nameservers and their glue records.

After some discussion in the comments it appears that the issue at hand was the specific behavior of the Godaddy UI for adding glue records.
Their UI apparently refuses to merge multiple *nameserver hostnames* but allows adding multiple addresses to the same *nameserver hostname*.